# Workflow Services Testing and Moq

Tags: unit-testing, moq, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I'm trying to unit test a Workflow Service by using [Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview&referringTitle=Home)
The goal is to mock the service's extensions in order to ensure that all steps are executed.

The mock objects don't seem to get called even though the extensions are registered in the Host. As expected, if the extensions are not registered an exception is thrown.

```
        WorkflowServiceTestHost host = null;

        try
        {
            Mock<ISubscriber> publisher = new Mock<ISubscriber>();
            Mock<IWebWorker> webWorker = new Mock<IWebWorker>();

            var voucher = new Voucher();

            using (host = new WorkflowServiceTestHost(workflowServiceFile, serviceAddress))
            {
                host.WorkflowExtensions.Add<ISubscriber>(() => publisher.Object);
                host.WorkflowExtensions.Add<IWebWorker>(() => webWorker.Object);

                host.Open();
                using (var factory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceInterface>(clientBinding, serviceAddress))
                {
                    var proxy = factory.CreateChannel() as IServiceInterface;

                    proxy.Process(voucher);
                }
            }

            **//These validations fail...**

            publisher.Verify(m => m.Push(It.IsAny<Voucher>()), Times.Once(), "ISubscriber.Push was not called.");
            webWorker.Verify(m => m.Done(It.IsAny<Voucher>()), Times.Once(), "IWebWorker.Done was not called.");

            // The host must be closed before asserting tracking
            // Explicitly call host.Close or exit the using block to do this.
        }
        finally
        {
            if (host != null)
            {
                host.Tracking.Trace(TrackingOptions.All);
            }
        }
```

The workflow runs as expected in IIS.

Thanks!

Edit: This error is being written in the Workflow Host output:

```
WorkflowInstance "Sequential Service" Unhandled Exception Source "Receive Process Message" 
Exception <System.NotSupportedException: Expression Activity type 'CSharpReference`1' requires compilation in order to run.  
Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled.
at System.Activities.Expressions.CompiledExpressionInvoker.InvokeExpression(ActivityContext activityContext)
at Microsoft.CSharp.Activities.CSharpReference`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecuteInResolutionContext(CodeActivityContext context)
at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteInResolutionContext[T](ActivityInstance parentInstance, Activity`1 expressionActivity)
at System.Activities.OutArgument`1.TryPopulateValue(LocationEnvironment targetEnvironment, ActivityInstance targetActivityInstance, ActivityExecutor executor)
at System.Activities.RuntimeArgument.TryPopulateValue(LocationEnvironment targetEnvironment, ActivityInstance targetActivityInstance, ActivityExecutor executor, Object argumentValueOverride, Location resultLocation, Boolean skipFastPath)
at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.InternalTryPopulateArgumentValueOrScheduleExpression(RuntimeArgument argument, Int32 nextArgumentIndex, ActivityExecutor executor, IDictionary`2 argumentValueOverrides, Location resultLocation, Boolean isDynamicUpdate)
at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.ResolveArguments(ActivityExecutor executor, IDictionary`2 argumentValueOverrides, Location resultLocation, Int32 startIndex)
at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)>
```

Comment: I haven't deal with C# expressions on workflows yet. Anyway, if I'm not wrong you've to compile the workflow before execute it; check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591618.aspx). It might be executing on IIS because the host (however it its; AppFabric?) is already compiling it implicitly but you should do it explicitly on your `WorkflowServiceTestHost`

Comment: What actually you try to test? The WorkflowServiceTestHost itself?

Comment: The workflow is comprised of a simple receive and two code activities; it doesn't have expressions at least that I'm aware of. I'm trying to test the Workflow and not the WorkflowServiceTestHost. The trace shown is part of the WorkflowServiceTestHost output produced by "host.Tracking.Trace(TrackingOptions.All);". Thank you all!

Comment: Well the error message is clear. You've to compile workflow before execute it. Check the link I've posted above. It's just a static method to call on workflow. You might not be using expressions explicitly but some other activity can, internally.

Comment: Hi Jota. It seems that the compilation only applies to self hosted workflows, am I wrong? If so, can you please provide an example that uses the WorkflowServiceTestHost? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just realized `WorkflowServiceTestHost` is a `Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting` class and not yours.

So, let's see if this is possible. As I saw on its [source code](https://wf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1081873) you can pass to the constructor the WorkflowService's object itself instead of the XAMLX file. Something like this:

```cs
// Load WorkflowService from .xamlx
// Actually this is the method WorkflowserviceTestHost uses when you pass a
// .xamlx so we're taking a step back to be able to compile the body
var wfService = XamlServices.Load("c:\\workflowservice.xamlx") as WorkflowService;

// Compile workflow body
CompileExpressions(wfService.Body);

// Now you can use WorkflowServiceTestHost
using (host = new WorkflowServiceTestHost(wfService, serviceAddress))
{
    // ... do your thing
}
```

`CompileExpressions` is taken from the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591618.aspx) that I gave you earlier.

---

That being said, it seems odd consider testing a WCF service as unit-testing. Unit tests should be focused on small activities of your service, those are truly unit-testable. Integration tests (or functional tests) is where you test services with all its dependencies (IIS\WAS, network, DBs, etc).

Comment: It worked, thanks a million. Regarding the comment about testing WCF methods, i agree with you that individual activities should be tested but i also think that the overall method that uses the activities should be tested as part of the unit tests. What is the difference between a WF workflow and a normal class method?

Comment: I see your point but a normal Workflow is different from a Workflow Service (which is no more than a WCF Service). In reality you're testing a web service through unit tests. Its odd to me but I can live with that. Furthermore, if Microsoft gives you a `WorkflowServiceTestHost` who am I to say otherwise :) Glad it worked!